# object contrib is not a member of package meta

Tags: scala, scalameta

I am trying to use the `isEqual` method in ScalaMeta.

```
import scala.meta.contrib._  

q"true".isEqual(q"true")
```

The import does not work:

```
object contrib is not a member of package meta
```

I am using `sbt` and I have the following in my `build.sbt`

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" %% "scalameta" % "4.0.0"
```

Where can I find the `isEqual` method for ScalaMeta? It appears to have been deprecated. I am following this [tutorial](https://scalameta.org/docs/trees/guide.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get access to Scalameta Contrib you can add the following dependency:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalameta" %% "contrib" % "4.0.0"
```

`isEqual` will be accessible, but `q` isn't. You can import it from `scala.meta._`.

The corrected example:

```
import scala.meta._
import scala.meta.contrib._

q"true".isEqual(q"true")
```